# mysql commands out of sync ( i use mysql not mysqli !)

Tags: php, mysql

today i faced a strange error witch i didn't faced before !

i Google it but not helped .

in here i found some problem like me BUT it was mysqli !

i am using mysql only not mysqli.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM s1_users WHERE id>4 AND ".time()." - timestamp < 300");
```

but i get

```
mysql commands out of sync you can't run this command now
```

i ran this query's hundred time before worked fine but i don't know why its telling me this error.

Comment: mysql_* is now deprecated. So you need to switch mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: What commands were running *before*...?!

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html, _you are calling client functions in the wrong order_.

Comment: @deceze i cant find out because many query's are running now.

Comment: @panther i didnt change anything its worked fine before. and i dont use mysql_use_result() ,  mysql_store_result() etc in my script even. how should i fix it ?

Comment: Thanks for the status report on the "strange error" you encountered. But... did you have a **question**?  (I can suggest a couple of question you might ask yourself. One is, "Should I be writing code that uses the deprecated mysql interface rather than **mysqli** or **PDO**?"

Comment: @spencer7593 yes i know i should move on from mysql_ and use pdo or mysqli . but i worked fine 2 days ago and i didnt do anything on server ! im wonder why its not working now ! ----- if i use this query : { SELECT id FROM s1_users WHERE id > 4 AND timestamp < 30 } its will work but the above query will not work :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: What causes this "strange error" to be returned?**

> `mysql commands out of sync you can't run this command now`

---

**A:** That error isn't strange. It's *expected* behavior.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

> If you get `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

---

**EDIT**

**Q: How do I debug my program?**

**A:** Check the return from your database interface calls for errors.

Reference: [How to debug small programs http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Make just a small change your code. Generate the SQL text into a string variable as a separate step, before prepare/execute of the generated SQL text. And before the prepare/execute, **output the string** containing the actual SQL text that's going to be submitted, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM s1_users WHERE id>4 AND ".time()." - timestamp < 300";
echo "SQL=" . $sql;  // for debugging
```

Then use a reference to `$sql` into your database interface function call (e.g. `prepare` or `execute`), pass the SQL statement to the database server. Here's a good pattern to follow: whenever you generate dynamic SQL and submit it to the database, do it in *two* steps. One step to generate the string, and a separate step that submits the generated SQL to the database.

When you run the code, the "`echo`" (or `vardump` or whatever) will show you the actual SQL text that's going to be submitted to the database.  You can take that SQL statement to a different  client, and test it. Likely, the database server is throwing an error on that statement, and you'll be able to spot it.

It's also likely that your code (which you haven't shown us) isn't checking the return from the database interface calls, to see if there was an error or not. I suspect your code is putting it's pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr. Evil style, and saying "I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?"

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Why do you need to supply the value from the PHP `time()` function as part of the SQL text? If you need the current time from the database server, the MySQL `NOW()` function would give that to you. If you need a unix timestamp version of that value (seconds since the beginning of the era in UTC), you can use the MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function, e.g. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())`.

If you can have a *static* string as a SQL statement that achieves what you need, that is usually a better option. If you need to supply literal values in a SQL statement, a better pattern for doing that is to use a **prepared  statement** with **bind placeholders**.

(Yes, there's a time and a place for everything, including dynamically generated SQL. But looking at what you are trying to achieve with your code, that time and place is *never* and *nowhere*.)

Comment: but it worked fine 2 days ago and i didnt do anything on server ! im wonder why its not working now ! ----- if i use this query : { SELECT id FROM s1_users WHERE id > 4 AND timestamp < 30 } its will work but the above query will not work :|

Comment: ... likely because the SQL statement you are submitting to the database is throwing an error, and likely because your code isn't checking for an error being returned. Use a *static* string as a SQL statement, rather than dynamically generating it. If you do have to generate the SQL text dynamically, do it in *two* steps, and get the actual SQL text you are going to submit to the database. If you have to supply values in the statement, use **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.